# I want to see who clicked the button on Discord.py, how do I do?

Tags: python, button, discord, bots

I'm making a bot for my Discord server, and I'd like to see who clicks the button for a little project. Can anyone help me?

```
async def bottoni(ctx):
    await buttons.send(
        content = "click!",
        channel = ctx.channel.id,
        components = [
            ActionRow([
                Button(
                    label="first",
                    style=ButtonType().Success,
                    custom_id = "button_one"
                ),
                Button(
                    label="second",
                    style=ButtonType().Danger,
                    custom_id = "button_two"
                )
            ])
        ]
    )

@buttons.click
async def button_one(ctx):
    interaction = buttons.click
    print(interaction.author, " clicked!")

@buttons.click
async def button_two(ctx):
    interaction = buttons.click
    print(interaction.author, " clicked!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the docs
[image: Docs]

So here is your code

```py
sync def bottoni(ctx):
    await buttons.send(
        content = "click!",
        channel = ctx.channel.id,
        components = [
            ActionRow([
                Button(
                    label="first",
                    style=ButtonType().Success,
                    custom_id = "button_one"
                ),
                Button(
                    label="second",
                    style=ButtonType().Danger,
                    custom_id = "button_two"
                )
            ])
        ]
    )

@buttons.click
async def button_one(ctx):
    interaction = buttons.click
    print(f"{ctx.member.name} just  clicked! button one")

@buttons.click
async def button_two(ctx):
    interaction = buttons.click
    print(f"{ctx.member.name} just  clicked! button two")
```

Comment: Um... Thanks but it doesn't work... it says: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: can I know what add-ons do you use like discord.py-components or discord.py-buttons so that I can look into it?

Comment: This is a copy and paste of the libraries: from discord_buttons_plugin import * - from discord.ext.commands import Bot - from discord.ext import commands - from discord.utils import get - from discord import client - from discord import Member - from time import sleep - import asyncio - import discord - import random - import json - import os

Comment: @Sphe just updated the answer let me know if it works

Comment: no, it doesn't work :( It says: AttributeError: 'InteractionContext' object has no attribute 'user'

Thanks by the way for your help!

Comment: @Sphe try replacing the `user` with `member` also i am sorry for so many comments and mistakes lol

Comment: Thank you! Now it works!! (sorry for writing you late, but I realized now that I didn't thank you!)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `interaction.user` to retrieve the user and you can use `interaction.user.id` to get the ID of said user.